# I am trying to write a new key value pair each time my bot joins a server. However the YAML file (seemingly) isn't updating upon dumping

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, discord.py

My code looks like this.

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_guild_join(self, guild): 
    guild_id = guild.id
   
    config['guilds'] = dict(guild_id=guild_id)
    config['guilds'][guild_id] = dict(enabled = False)
    config['guilds'][guild_id] = dict(chance = 0.05) 

    with open('config.yaml', 'w') as file: 
        try: 
            yaml.dump(config, file, default_flow_style=False)
        except yaml.YAMLError as e:
                await print(e)
```

And the output to the .yaml file looks like this:

[image]

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What errors are returned from it? Is it silent?

Comment: There are no errors returned from it, it is silent.

Comment: try without `await` for printing

Comment: Nothing is printed.

Comment: print() is not a coroutine, why are you awaiting it?

Comment: It is a mistake.

Comment: my gut is telling me you are dumping to a different file with the same filename in some other directory (because I've done that multiple times). Try absolute-pathing your file path?

Comment: I tried absolute-pathing it, that did not help

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate, which makes me think it's not the YAML part that's wrong. You might have to give a bit more information before we can help you.